# Bootloader issue - How do I completely remove Linux from my system? fully detailed description

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, efibootmgr

The *goal* was to successfully **install Windows 10 upgrade.**

System configuration :
Dell Inspiron 3537,
 i5 4th gen processor,
 6GB RAM,
 1TB HDD,
 2GB AMD Graphics.

Before install :
I have a **Dual-boot system** with Ubuntu GNOME alongside my genuine Windows 8.1.

I assumed there would be a problem with the bootmanager so I decided to **remove the Linux from my system**. Followed the instructions given in the how-to-geek website tutorial(linked at the end).

Accordingly,I **deleted 2 partitions** 65GB and 2GB(I guess swap partion). Screenshot added to the gdrive folder

Next,I booted into Windows Repair from Disc
and entered in cmd:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

After removal the **problem** began,(gdrive link with screenshots given at the end)

The **first boot screen**:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.2

    Minimal Bash-like line editing is supported. For the first word,TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
    grub>exit
    Boot succeeded-info
```

The **second boot screen**:

```
Boot Manager (windows)
```

The **third boot screen**:

```
Windows 8.1/10 boot up (Dell logo)
```

Then the system finally starts Windows.

I **installed Windows 10 upgrade**,still the **same problem**.

**Please guide me** through removing Linux entirely (removing grub) from the system.
I want to clean-install Windows 10 of which I know the process how-to-do-it.

Do I remove the EFI partition too?

Do I just directly perform a clean install?

Please help. Thanks a lot!

> Links:
>
> Gdrive screenshots: https://goo.gl/hUZIKG
>
> How-to-geek tutorial: http://goo.gl/Wqk4pe

Comment: For anyone looking for the answer, it got posted here (Upvote there helpful): https://superuser.com/questions/957107/bootloader-issue-how-do-i-completely-remove-linux-from-my-system-fully-detail